# Changin theme of webIDE in firefox

Tags: firefox, web-ide

I want to change the webIDE theme in Mozilla Firefox. I want the editor to be dark colored. I googled it but couldn't find anything.

Comment: What web IDE are you talking about?

Comment: He is talking about this here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2xmj4W8O3E4

Answer (score 1):

WebIDE? Did you mean Mozilla Developer Edition?
You want to revert to it's original theme but the editor still remain dark?
I think it's impossible because the editor is dependent with the themes you used.

if you want to change the color of your Toolbar (I don't know what it is called) just go to **Open Menu** *(the burger icon)* ->**Add-ons***( If you installed MDE it's theme will be available)* -> **Appearance**. then Enabled it.

To enter to Dev mode (MDE)just press F12 and your editor is not really black. There a link below, hope it helps you.

MDE Flavor Themes Enabled:
[image: MDE Flavor Themes Enabled]

http://techlemonade.com/how-to-change-firefox-developer-edition-dark-theme-to-light-theme/